# Undefined error after firefox 4 beta update

Tags: javascript, str-replace, firefox4

Can somebody check my code and tell me where I'm doing wrong. I'm very poor in javascript and using this code from long time, after firefox update from 3.5 to 4 beta, I'm getting undefined error.

```
function Convert_ONE2TWO()
{
    var arrTWO = new Array( "a", "e", "i");
    var arrONE = new Array( "A", "E", "I");
    str=document.frmConvert.txtONE.value; //input from ONE
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) //Loop for all letters
        {
        strTemp=new RegExp(arrONE[i], "ig");
        str=str.replace(strTemp,arrTWO[i]); //Replacing
        }
    document.frmConvert.txtTWO.value=str.toString(); //output to TWO
}

<form name="frmConvert" action="" method="get">
<textarea rows="5" cols="90" name="txtONE"></textarea>
<input name="btnConvertg" value="Create TWO" onclick="Convert_ONE2TWO();" type="Button">
<textarea rows="5" cols="90" name="txtTWO"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't understand, What to accept?

Comment: Do you test all your code in beta versions of software?

Comment: @alex: Also it marks the question as closed and answered to the community for archival and organisational benefits.

Comment: Oh! I don't know about this! I got a lot of help here, especially for my first question, I'll now check how to accept, and accept answers I liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. You have three array elements, but perform four loop iterations.

Use `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` and remember that array indices start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: No, even if I use 4 instead of 3, i'm getting error. In safari also I'm getting this error, but ignored as I can do my work with firefox, now I have to face the problem.

Comment: @user625118: Correct this fundamental error in your post's code, then we can proceed.